# The marker image sensor Method name on Augmented Reality for Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, augmented-reality, marker

I use framework Pro Android Augmented Reality.

I wonder what Method is used in the sensor marker.

Marker that is used as a color picture black and white square and an extension is .patt, but I would like to change the marker image is an image that is a different color and a .png or .jpg file extension that I mentioned this method must be used?

I understand that OpenGL is a method to sensor marker?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K I didn't ask the old question. I want to know what method is called. Not a method named OpenGL? if so, change the source code editor, a color marker image sensor.

Answer (score 0):

Go to local data source class and add your bitmap to 'cachedMarkers' Arraylist . Like this

Marker home = new IconMarker("" +name,30,10, 0,Color.WHITE, bitmap);
cachedMarkers.add(home);
ARData.addMarkers('cached`enter code here`Markers');

Like this you can add any image to that point .. Pass parametes to Icon Marker class as per method